# Copy xpath Doesn't Provide Correct xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I've been trying to click a button using selenium package in python. I've been having trouble figuring out how to identify the button, though. After way too much time, I tried manually copying the `xpath` from the javascript console, but get a `NoSuchElementException` when I try to call `driver.find_element_from_xpath('<xpath>')`.

I'm really not sure how that's possible. The HTML is extremely long - what I'm ultimately trying to locate is nested under multiple table, body, td, tr tags. Here's the element though:

```
<a href="Javascript:void" onclick="javascript:toggleDisplay(this, trAK);return false;">Alaska</a>
```

When I clicked "Copy Xpath" in Chrome, it returned this string: `//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a`

I'm pretty new to this so can anyone help me understand why this won't work and/or what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Alaska"))).click()
  ```
- Using (logical) `XPATH` (instead of absolute xpath):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick, 'toggleDisplay') and text()='Alaska']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Awesome! I did not realize a JavaScript element would have to be called like that. I have almost 0 knowledge of html or js. This explains things and got my stuff working!
I am curious how you were able to locate that element so easily? I tried so many `driver.find_element_by...` calls and the Alaska string never did it for me